# Calculate an estimate of the data

Tags: variance, means

The data examines the head tilting preference of humans when kissing. The data was collected by observing kissing couples and found that of 124 kissing pairs, 80 turned their heads to the right and 44 turned their heads to the left.

Calculate an estimate of the preference for humans turning their heads to the right.

Hi, I'm unsure about what the question means by "estimate of the preference...". Are they asking for the mean and variance? If so, is the mean = 80 and how can I find the estimate for variance?

Comment: It's a romantic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming binomial distribution:

[image]

The variance is $28.3871$.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is a rather dumb question but how do I know if it's a binomial distribution?

Comment: You don't.  You must make this assumption.  If you don't assume some distribution, you cannot answer this question.